# give different value to the popup using enyojs

Tags: enyo

I have a repeater In which I am displaying different values.On click of each row I want to display few values.But in the enyo example the content of the popup is popup.....

This content I want to change.I have tried as below

I have the popup-

```
{name: "basicPopup", kind: "enyo.Popup", floating: true, centered: true,
        style: "background-color: yellow; padding: 10px", onHide: "popupHidden", components: [
            {content: "Popup..."}
        ]
    },
```

the mathod i used on tap of each row is

```
tapped: function(inSender, inEvent) {
 alert(inSender.getContent())
 this.$.basicPopup.setValue(inSender.getContent());
  this.$.basicPopup.show();
},
```

But by this the vale of the popup is not changing.I want to change the value.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is setContent() on the component inside the Popup OR destroyClientControls() on the Popup and then createComponents() to add what you want in there.

To do it the first way, you want to provide a name for that component, something like:

{name: "popupContent", content: "Popup..."}

and then use this.$.popupContent.setContent("foo");